# change date format into existing table sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a datetime value, which is in the form of: '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000'. How can I convert it to a datetime value in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format instead and save it in a SQL Server 2012 database?

Here is my C# code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();                          
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Convert(nvarchar(max), DATEDIFF(day, '" + sStartDate + "','" + sEndDate + "')+1)";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: Your question is a bit bad formatted. Do you mean the following?"I have a datetime value, which is in the form of: '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000'. How can I convert it to a datetime value in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format instead and save it in a SQL Server 2012 database?". Do I get your question right?

Comment: yes vahid now that date format is 2015-03-15 00:00:00.000' i want change into dd/mm/yyyy format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEDIFF(day, '" + sStartDate + "','" + sEndDate + "')+1, 103)";
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CONVERT_TSQL%29;k%28SQL12.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1%29;k%28SQL12.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1%29;k%28MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT%29;k%28DevLang-TSQL%29&rd=true)

Comment: @Devart-since 2 years back u r saw this error now what i got could u help me plz...... that error is
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. select datediff(day,'20/10/2010','30/10/2010') i need this

Comment: i tried with convertion select Convert(nvarchar(max),DATEDIFF(day,'15-05-2015','25-05-2015'),103) and select Convert(nvarchar(max), datediff(day,CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/05/2015', 3),CONVERT(DATETIME,'15/05/2015', 3)),120) and select Convert(nvarchar(max),datediff(day,Convert(nvarchar(max),'15/05/2015',120),Conve‌​rt(nvarchar(max),'25/05/2015',120)),120)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change the data type of your column from datetime to char(24)/varchar(24). then you can use the following method to change the format of your value into a desired format.

```
SELECT  RIGHT('0'+ CAST(DATEPART(DAY, '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000') AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '/'
    + RIGHT('0'+CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000') AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '/'
    + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, '2015-03-15 00:00:00.000') AS VARCHAR(4));
```

Code Analysis:

First we acquire the DAY part of the date using DATEPART built-in function. As this value could have one or two character(s) length, we added a constant '0' to the first of this value, and then cut the last 2 characters from it. So for instance, if the DAY is equal to 24 then after adding a '0' to it's beginning it would changed to 024 and then we cut the last two character, which is 24. But if the DAY is equal to 9, then we add a '0' to it's beginning. So now we have 09, and by cutting the last 2 characters we have 09 again. This can guarantee the dd and MM format.

Note that if your column in the database has datetime or datetime2 data type, then you need to solve this issue in a different way.Read more [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Convert(nvarchar(max), DATEDIFF(day, '" + sStartDate + "','" + sEndDate + "')+1,105)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        objEmployee.EmployeeName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
select datediff(day,'20/10/2010','30/10/2010')  i need this

Comment: i tried with convertion                                                                     select Convert(nvarchar(max),DATEDIFF(day,'15-05-2015','25-05-2015'),103)    and     select Convert(nvarchar(max), datediff(day,CONVERT(DATETIME, '15/05/2015', 3),CONVERT(DATETIME,'15/05/2015', 3)),120)    and     select Convert(nvarchar(max),datediff(day,Convert(nvarchar(max),'15/05/2015',120),Convert(nvarchar(max),'25/05/2015',120)),120)

Comment: @Sreevardhan.wardon you need to use your datetime value in natural format(yyyyMMdd). In this case you can easily send it as a parameter to any datetime related function such as DateDiff. SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '20150515', '20150525'). You got that error because, SQL Server is unable to convert the '15-05-2015' to datetime and it throws as exception. You may resolve this issue by making some changes on you PC's or server's local(Not sure!)

Comment: @Sreevardhan.wardon and if you want to reconstruct a new string representing the date diff of two dates in dd/mm/yyyy format, you need to write a scalar function to do this job for you. You may find similar functions of course, by doing some search in stackoverflow.

Comment: -select convert(nvarchar(max),getdate(),103)
is working but for datediff function is not working what is the problem one is working onther one not working

Comment: GetDate() is working because it's return type is compatible with a datetime value.In my PC it returns yyyy-mm-dd which is a valid format and using 103 format code can easily convert it to dd/mm/yyyy format. But in your case, your value is not a compatible datetime value(dd-mm-yyyy) and this causes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you're storing date information in a database then you should **use your database's** `date` **type. A date is a date, not some arbitrary format.** Doing so will allow you to safely rely on all of the nice date functions that are built in to SQL Server and save you from an entire class of problems.

If you find yourself constantly reformating the date into a string for reporting purposes then throw the conversion logic in a view/TVF and use that object as your reporting source.

If your only problem is displaying a datetime as a date then you can use:

```
select Convert(nvarchar(10), SysDateTime(), 103) as [dd/mm/yyyy];
```

Comment: i am getting that error at execute scalar and here my code.... cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Convert(nvarchar(max), DATEDIFF(day, '" + sStartDate + "','" + sEndDate + "')+1,105)";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        objEmployee.EmployeeName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();